# How to initialise an app with data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a single file component called Foo:

```
<template>
<div>
  This is the app. X  is {{ x }}, y is {{ y }}
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
   return { x: 'hello x' };
  },
}
</script>
```

And I'm initializing my app like:

```
// somewhere here 'node' gets set to a DOM node,
// and 'y' is created.
import Vue from 'vue';
import Foo from './Foo.vue';
const app = new Vue({             
  'el': node,                     
  data: {y},
  render: h => h(Foo)             
});
```

This is an oversimplification in that 'y' is actually an object not just a simple string. If that makes a difference.

I know how to pass props etc for *child components*, but I'm struggling to get the main config data into the top level Vue app!

Answer (score 1):

**Foo.vue :**

add `props:['y']`

```
<template>
<div>
  This is the app. X  is {{ x }}, y is {{ y }}
</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
  props:['y']
    data() {
      return {
        x: 'hello x'
      };
    },
  }
</script>
```

**main.js**

add `template:'<Foo :y="y"'/>` to the vue instance and `node` should be a valid html element

```js
// somewhere here 'node' gets set to a DOM node,
// and 'y' is created.
import Vue from 'vue';
import Foo from './Foo.vue';
const app = new Vue({
  'el': node,
  data: {
    y: "some content"
  },
  template: "<Foo :y='y'/>"
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This requires using the compiler-included build of vuejs which I had hoped to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.

In `Foo.vue` add `props`:

```
<template>
<div>
  This is the app. X  is {{ x }}, y is {{ y }}
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {return { x: 'hello x' };},
  props: [ 'y' ],
}
</script>
```

Then in the main js that creates the app:

```
// somewhere here 'node' gets set to a DOM node,
// and 'y' is created.
import Vue from 'vue';
import Foo from './Foo.vue';
const app = new Vue({             
  'el': node,
  render: h => h(Foo, {props: {y})
});
```

This way y gets passed in as a prop, but without resorting to using `template` which requires the heaviere compiler-included Vue build.

The advantage of this is that my CMS can spit out chunks of the page that should each be Vue apps, can include configuration for each of those apps, and can thten create all the Vue apps which differ only in their content.

While the focus of documentation on single file components seems to be a monolithic single page app, that's not what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Resolution

If you must use the data of top level Vue app, you can make it by using `$parent` or `$root`. Then you can use `$data` of that Vue instance to access its data. Here is the [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-parent) of Vue instance.

With `$parent` you will get a Vue instance of one component's parent.

```
this.$parent.$data.y
```

With `$root` you will get the root Vue instance of the current component tree.

```
this.$root.$data.y
```

So the **Foo.vue** will be like this:

```
<template>
  <div>This is the app. X is {{ x }}, y is {{ y }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return { x: "x" };
  },
  computed: {
    y: function() {
      return this.$parent.$data.y;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can see the live code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/40yq0onp9w).

#### More

But it's not a recommended way. If you want to pass data to child component, you can use `props`. If you don't like props, you can use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to make a global data store where to put your top level options.